# Selenium not finding element by xpath, id, class etc. Tried explicit wait

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to write a script that automates our reporting.
I am attempting to find the username element with selenium but it is not finding it by class, xpath, id etc.

I have tried implementing an explicit wait but to no avail.

I am incredibly new to the world of python so apologies for stupid errors.
Here is what I have:

```
`from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
chromedriver = r"C:\Users\LouisKempson\Desktop\chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("http://ba-app02:8080/InfoViewApp/logon.jsp")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
username = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "usernameTextEdit")))
username.send_keys('opsteams')`
```

error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LouisKempson/PycharmProjects/Test/venv/Lib/Sign_In_Firefox.py", line 9, in <module>
    username = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "usernameTextEdit")))
  File "C:\Users\LouisKempson\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please try below solution

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
chromedriver = r"C:\Users\LouisKempson\Desktop\chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("http://ba-app02:8080/InfoViewApp/logon.jsp")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
inputElement.send_keys("opsteams")
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion. I now get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LouisKempson/PycharmProjects/Test/venv/Lib/Sign_In_Firefox.py", line 8, in <module>
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: Updated solution can you please try now

Comment: also please post your DOm if above solution is not working because i cant access your http://ba-app02:8080/InfoViewApp/logon.jsp link

Comment: Now this :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LouisKempson/PycharmProjects/Test/venv/Lib/Sign_In_Firefox.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver.maximize_window()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'maximize_window'

Comment: I'm sorry I dont know how to get DOM. I am rubbish with computers but HTML is :
<input type="text" name="username" value="" style="width:200px" class="inputTextBox" id="usernameTextEdit">

Comment: no worries so in your solution try to increase implicit wait time to 10 sec. please check updated solution and to get DOM you need to press Ctrl+Shift+ I

Comment: Doesn't seem to be, I thought it may be an issue with switching to Iframe but doesnt seem to be that either

Comment: post your DOM here

Comment: I dont know how to do that I'm sorry

Comment: Can I access your site ?

Comment: I dont think so Im sorry. I think you have to be on our network. When I inspect elements there are mentions of javaScript. Could that be the issue?

Comment: if i print screen the html and post would that be of use?

Comment: it seems I can only add one picture and it is currently being peer reviewed. Is there another way to contact you? PS. I really appreciate this.